# Функции. Ответственность за проверку наличия аргументов и их типов

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Изучаю программирование и javaScript.

Разбиваю большую функцию на маленькие. Возникло затруднение с проверкой аргументов.

Не понятны вопросы типа:

- Вызывающая или вызываемая функция несет ответственность за то что бы типы аргументов и их количество соответствовали ожидаемым?
- Когда производить проверку аргументов, а когда ее можно опустить?
- Как правильно проверять типы?
- и т.д.

Созрел закономерный вопрос: существуют ли какие-нибудь общепринятые(или не общепринятые) соглашения на этот счет?

Comment: какого рода проверку? проверку типов?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman проверка типов и количества(наличия всех необходимых аргументов).

Comment: добавьте это в вопрос.